# Using AJAX to get URLs of a DOM element on external page (same domain) which are generated by JS-enabled user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bigcommerce

I hope the title is not too convoluted to understand...   Please have some patience while I explain as the restrictions of the platform I am working on make this convoluted.

I am working on a functionality feature on a commercial eCommerce platform, ie BigCommerce.  This causes many restrictions in terms of what and how things can be done.

### What I am trying to accomplish:

- I need to bring **"color swatch connected to the appropriate product image color when user clicks a color in the colorswatch"** functionality to a categories page of the site.
- This functionality already exists on the individual product pages, however there is no straight forward way to bring it to the categories page, hence this script.
- So essentially, when a user is on a product page, they see a line of little colored boxes (ie, red, green, blue, yellow, etc) which when clicked, will bring up the appropriate product color image into the main image DOM element (so if they click red, the red product appears in the main image DOM element, if they click green, the green product appears, and so on)

### The problem in implementing this:

1. The rule sets of matching a certain color to a certain image are not available to developers for some terrible reasons.  They are not even available thru the API with any language (ruby, python, PHP).
2. On the product page, where the feature exists, the URLs are not present as they are automatically generated by backend PHP (I think) when a user clicks the boxes.  (to be honest, I am not sure how the URLs to the images are generated but I can't find any reference to the URLs either directly or by dynamic rules.  I've scoured through all the JS manually and through some searches and can't find any reference to this functionality).
3. I've written a script to imitate a user click as this seems to be the only action that changes the image.  I've also tried writing a script that reproduces the same behavior as clicking (ie, change class of one box from selectedValue to nothing, and set the clicked box to selectedValue, but this does not change the DOM element).  The script I am using utilizes .click().   Can click() be used with AJAX to imitate user behavior on an external page, generating dynamic content, and then to bring the result of that action to the current page?

### My question:

- Is it possible to achieve this by

  1. using AJAX to visit each product page,
  2. imitate user clicks on each color box,
  3. record each URL of the image DOM element that is changed by the click,
  4. then bring those URLs with their respective color values to the current page
  5. and utilize them in recreating the color-swatch-click behavior on that page?

#### Is there some other way you can think of to accomplish this?

I am more than happy to share the JS I wrote, along with the relevant HTML from each of the two pages, but I do not think it will necessarily help to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure that I have come up with the solution you are looking for. The best you can do is load the entire page and run a script to do all the navigating for you. But this doesn't work cross site. If you are working on the same project, use a submit page in order to process your request. But i'm not sure if you are able to do that.

At any rate. Here is some code to through at you.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/u8wbasdk/2/)

```
<button class='clickable' data-href='page.php'>URL One</button>
<button class='clickable' data-href='otherpage.php'>URL Two</button>
<input name='color' class='data' value='black'/>
<input name='color2' class='data' value='yellow'/>
<div class='text-center' id='container'></div>
```

JS

```
$('.clickable').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).data('href');
    var data = $('.data').serialize();
    $.post(href, data, function (html) {
        $('#container').html(html);
    });
});
```